# Kernel panics after hitting a breakpoint during jtag debugging using gdb

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, jtag

I am trying to debug linux kernel running on sabre lite board using jtag and gdb on my host machine. During debugging I insert a break point at "do_fork()" and allow the kernel to continue its execution.
As soon as I enter "ls" command on my sabre lite board the breakpoint gets hit after which the kernel panics.

Here is the log generated on the console terminal of sabre lite board:

```
root@mx6q:~# ls
[   94.725966] Unhandled prefetch abort: breakpoint debug exception (0x002) at 0x00094d74
[   94.733935] Internal error: : 2 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[   94.738918] Modules linked in: ov5642_camera ov5640_camera_mipi mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_g
[   94.754748] CPU: 1 PID: 406 Comm: sh Not tainted 3.10.45 #1
[   94.760343] task: dcb78f00 ti: dc8ec000 task.ti: dc8ec000
[   94.765781] PC is at do_fork+0x0/0x368
[   94.769554] LR is at SyS_clone+0x24/0x2c
[   94.773497] pc : [<c002ae3c>]    lr : [<c002b264>]    psr: 800f0013
[   94.773497] sp : dc8edf90  ip : b6f3d068  fp : dc8edfa4
[   94.784993] r10: 00000000  r9 : dc8ec000  r8 : c000e304
[   94.790235] r7 : 00000078  r6 : b6ec0000  r5 : 00000000  r4 : b6f3d068
[   94.796778] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 01200011
[   94.803325] Flags: Nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[   94.810477] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 2c89004a  DAC: 00000015
[   94.816240] Process sh (pid: 406, stack limit = 0xdc8ec238)
[   94.821830] Stack: (0xdc8edf90 to 0xdc8ee000)
[   94.826208] df80:                                     b6f3d068 c011aa24 00000000   dc8e8
[   94.834410] dfa0: c000e180 c002b24c b6f3d068 00000000 01200011 00000000 00000000 00000
[   94.842612] dfc0: b6f3d068 00000000 b6ec0000 00000078 b6f3d4c0 00000196 000e5e08 bed5c
[   94.850813] dfe0: 00000000 bed52940 b6f3d000 b6e25640 600f0010 01200011 fd3b4088 0000f
[   94.859001] Backtrace: 
[   94.861512] [<c002b240>] (SyS_clone+0x0/0x2c) from [<c000e180>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0)
[   94.869887] Code: e92dd800 e24cb004 e5801188 e89da800 (e1200070) 
[   94.876596] ---[ end trace 3e3aa32a078125f3 ]---
     Stopping Serial Getty on ttymxc1...
[  OK  ] Stopped Serial Getty on ttymxc1.
     Starting Serial Getty on ttymxc1...
[   94.957982] Unhandled prefetch abort: breakpoint debug exception (0x002) at 0xb6e5e4a0
[   94.966066] Internal error: : 2 [#2] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[   94.971058] Modules linked in: ov5642_camera ov5640_camera_mipi mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_g
[   94.986894] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: systemd Tainted: G      D      3.10.45 #1
[   94.993705] task: dc078000 ti: dc05c000 task.ti: dc05c000
[   94.999143] PC is at do_fork+0x0/0x368
[   95.002916] LR is at SyS_clone+0x24/0x2c
[   95.006859] pc : [<c002ae3c>]    lr : [<c002b264>]    psr: 80070013
[   95.006859] sp : dc05df90  ip : b6d2c068  fp : dc05dfa4
[   95.018355] r10: 00000000  r9 : dc05c000  r8 : c000e304
[   95.023596] r7 : 00000078  r6 : b6eed000  r5 : bef7cfc8  r4 : b6d2c068
[   95.030138] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 01200011
[   95.036685] Flags: Nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[   95.043837] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 2c57c04a  DAC: 00000015
[   95.049599] Process systemd (pid: 1, stack limit = 0xdc05c238)
[   95.055448] Stack: (0xdc05df90 to 0xdc05e000)
[   95.059827] df80:                                     b6d2c068 000b9ec1 00000000 dc058
[   95.068028] dfa0: c000e180 c002b24c b6d2c068 bef7cfc8 01200011 00000000 00000000 00000 
[   95.076228] dfc0: b6d2c068 bef7cfc8 b6eed000 00000078 b6d2c4c0 00000001 00000000 bef74
[   95.084429] dfe0: 00000001 bef7cfc8 b6d2c000 b6e52640 60070010 01200011 fd7b4088 0000f
[   95.092616] Backtrace: 
[   95.095125] [<c002b240>] (SyS_clone+0x0/0x2c) from [<c000e180>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0)
[   95.103502] Code: e92dd800 e24cb004 e5801188 e89da800 (e1200070) 
[   95.109750] ---[ end trace 3e3aa32a078125f4 ]---
[   95.116889] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
[   95.116889] 
[   95.126041] CPU0: stopping
[   95.128760] CPU: 0 PID: 163 Comm: systemd-journal Tainted: G      D      3.10.45 #1
[   95.136418] Backtrace: 
[   95.138902] [<c0011f24>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [<c0012138>] (show_stack+0x1)
[   95.147342]  r6:c0a70e40 r5:00000000 r4:00000005 r3:00000000
[   95.153072] [<c0012120>] (show_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c078d698>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x2)
[   95.161083] [<c078d678>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x28) from [<c00145d4>] (handle_IPI+0x124/0x)
[   95.169268] [<c00144b0>] (handle_IPI+0x0/0x14c) from [<c0008628>] (gic_handle_irq+0x5)
[   95.177718] [<c00085cc>] (gic_handle_irq+0x0/0x64) from [<c0793140>] (__irq_svc+0x40/)
[   95.185985] Exception stack(0xdc6e5df0 to 0xdc6e5e38)
[   95.191041] 5de0:                                     c0acb800 600f0013 00003d1d 00000
[   95.199224] 5e00: c0c7fb00 00000001 dc64b000 00000001 00000000 dc00e400 c0acb4c0 dc6e4
[   95.207405] 5e20: dc6e5e48 dc6e5e38 c00d8cd8 c0792858 a00f0013 ffffffff
[   95.214021]  r7:dc6e5e24 r6:ffffffff r5:a00f0013 r4:c0792858
[   95.219749] [<c079282c>] (_raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0x0/0x54) from [<c00d8cd8>] (re)
[   95.229676] [<c00d8b1c>] (release_pages+0x0/0x200) from [<c01006f8>] (free_pages_and_)
[   95.239345] [<c0100684>] (free_pages_and_swap_cache+0x0/0xac) from [<c00f38b8>]
```

and on my host side:

```
Breakpoint 4, do_fork (clone_flags=18874385, stack_start=0, 
Sending packet: $mdc8edfa8,4#94...Packet received: 68d0f3b6
stack_size=stack_size@entry=0, parent_tidptr=0x0 <__vectors_start>, 
child_tidptr=child_tidptr@entry=0xb6f3d068) at kernel/fork.c:1570
1570    kernel/fork.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Can some one please guide me I am stuck on this issue..........

Comment: You could try with kgdb.

Comment: could it be because you are debugging a PREEMPT SMP configuration? http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-arm-kernel/2010-December/033443.html

Answer (score 0):

kernal panic is when there is something exceptionally wrong with the kernal module. Also at times, the error messages displayed may be the effect of the error and not the cause.